# Batch - Search if a variable contains spaces

Tags: batch-file

I have a variable that I need to check if it contains spaces, and exit if it does.
I have this code:

```
if not [%VAR%]==[%VAR: =%] exit 1
```

.. but it does not work for spaces. I can use it for other characters though. For example looking for "/" works with same code:

```
if not [%VAR%]==[%VAR:/=%] exit 1
```

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do as you need: double quotes are always the solution for spaces, and also with some other characters.

```
if not "%VAR%"=="%VAR: =%" exit 1
```

Comment: +1 :) Faster than me. But it will fail for values with a quote inside.

Comment: Thank you. This works for spaces indeed. It does not work for stars though.  
  

`if not "%VAR%"=="%VAR:*=%" exit 1`

Comment: The `*` is a special operator when it appears as the first character in the search term.  See **if /?** for details.  There are other characters it doesn't work with also, like `=`

Answer (score 4):

While the answer from foxidrive will handle the problem for simple cases and is the obvious answer (and yes, this is what i usually use), it will fail for values with a quote inside

*"If needed"*  this should handle the marginal cases

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in (".%var:"=%.") do exit 1
```

The "trick" is to enclose the value with removed quotes and tokenize the string using `for` command. To avoid spaces at the start and end of the string from being removed a pair of aditional dots are included. If the string do not include a space, it will only have one token. But the `for` command is requesting the second token, so the code inside will not be executed for strings without a space in them.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why it does not work for stars?  
  

`if not "%VAR%"=="%VAR:*=%" exit 1`

Comment: @user3683832, for the why, foxidrive answered you: in substring replaces it is used as a starting wildcard. In your case, with the construct you are using, you can do `if not "%VAR%"=="%VAR:**=%" exit 1` that is, instead of replacing just a asterisk, replace all the characters until a asterisk is found. This will remove all the characters up to the asterisk if at least one is present, but will not remove anything if not present, making your `if` work