# Batch: How do I replace a specific part of text in a variable, without changing everything else?

Tags: batch-file

So I'm trying to make a search engine that, when you input a search string, replaces the spaces with a "+", and it'd be helpful if someone pointed out which commands I can use to achieve that.

So far I haven't found anyone that has the same question, which is why I'm posting it here. I've found [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635754/batch-search-if-a-variable-contains-spaces) with a way to detect spaces in a variable:

```
if not "%VAR%"=="%VAR: =%"
```

but no way to replace them.

Any hints?

P.S.: Please, do not recommend me PowerShell or other scripting languages/methods like I saw some people do, I have my reason for using batch and I'm going to stick to it.

Comment: Well, the (incomplete) code you posted compares *a certain string* with *the string with spaces removed* for equality...

Comment: `Set "VAR=%VAR: =+%"`

Comment: I'm gonna be that annoying guy but there is no reason that batch is essential for this, PowerShell is the way to go, the syntax in batch is pretty horrible...Trust me I worked for a long time in CMD and PowerShell blows it out the water. I'm curious why you would need to stick with CMD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let me explain how substitution works.

```
set "var=This is a line with spaces"
set "var=%var: =+%"
echo %var%
```

in the second `set` we `set var` to `%var%` again, but we use substitution of spaces. Everything after `:` up to `=` is the search function and everything after `=` up to the `%` is the replace function. So `%var: =+%` means find all the space and replace with `+` Hence the outcome of the above code will be:

```
This+is+a+line+with+spaces
```

Obviously the variable can be manipulated multiple times:

```
set "var=This is a line with spaces"
set "var=%var: =+%"
set "var=%var:spaces=pluses%
echo %var%
```

you can also use the substitution to do comparisons without doing substitution using `set`:

```
set "var=This is a line with spaces"
if /i "%var: =+%"=="This+is+a+line+with+spaces" echo Matched!
```

I suggest you read the help by running `set /?` from cmdline.